# What does the parameter -S, when I run a php script in console

Tags: php

What does the parameter `"-S"`, when I run a php script in console.

For example:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

Comment: From `man php`: -S addr:port   Start built-in web server on the given local address and port

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Please tell me where I can find description of all available parameters

Comment: Type the command: `php --help` or `man php`.

Comment: [PHP Command line usage - options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Comment: See also http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php and [`php --help`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 1):

It tells php to use the built-in server and not to wait for external - Apache, nginx, lighthttpd, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.